# How to send email only to users that are created by admin

Tags: laravel

This is my User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'card_id',
        'assigned_to',
        'user_type',//4 = admin 3 = manager 2 = business 1 = courier 0 = client
        'password_changed_at',
        'email_verified_at',
    ];
```

When the user is created he has a role based on it's user_type.Users with type 1,2 or 3 are all created by an admin.
Basically I want to send an email to users that are created by admin with their credentials.
This is how i send the email to the user

```
public function createUser(){
        $this->validate();

        $randomPass = Str::random(8);
        $userCreds = ['email' => $this->email, 'password' => $randomPass];

        try{
            User::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $this->name,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($randomPass),
                'email_verified_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'user_type' => (int)$this->selectedUser,
                'assigned_to' => (int)$this->selectedAssigned,
                'doctor_type' => $this->selectTypeDoc,
            ]);

            Mail::to($this->email)->send(new SendUserMail($userCreds));

            $this->reset();
            $this->emitUp('refreshParent');
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('swal-insert');

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('createUser-error');
        }

        $this->closeModal();

    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? With EventServiceProvider or with a controller?

Comment: A cleaner way would be to use an observer, if the user has a role 0, 1, 2 or 3 it can be sent the email. Link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers

Comment: The admin only creates users with roles from 1-3 The clients create their account themselves in this case role 0

Comment: Is it not best to check in this route if `Auth::user()` is admin, and send the mail if he is? I would recommend sending the mail in a job with a queue tho, that would make the admin's UI-speed alot faster.

Comment: The best way is to combine an observer with a queue that emits a job to send the mail. The mail doesn't have to be sent immediately (some minor delay is acceptable I guess) hence the job and the observer can check for the correct role and only queue the job if the role_id is 1-3.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example if possible I'm new to laravel and i dont have a lot of experience

Comment: how about event & listener ?  I feel that using observer for only one event is a bit overkill, and I know observer is Model Scope meaning it will also trigger if the client which is the id = 0 will also sent with the email. since you only want it to send to ids 1, 2, 3.